# Error while running a new project in meteor in windows 7

Tags: meteor

I am a newbie to meteor js. I am getting errors while creating a new project.
Am using Windows 7.what should i do?[image of the error incurred is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vcQ.jpg)

Comment: Can you include some details on what code you've used?

Comment: I installed meteor js, then created an app using meteor create app_name. then cd app_name and then meteor run. I have also shared the image of the errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like meteor couldn't download the packages it needs to do the build - I think you need to try again when you are online

Comment: I had uninstalled and installed it many times. Even used meteor reset  command and then gave meteor run, but still same result.

Comment: If you look at the log, you'll see that it's failing to reach the following IP address: https://94.31.29.131/ - if you follow that you should get this message: "You are hitting the MaxCDN San Francisco Datacenter" If it times out, then you have some kind of network connectivity problem (are you not allowed to reach this address?)

Comment: yeah, i did get that message. So is there any other way for creating a project in meteor using windows??

Comment: Just try it again, hopefully it will work. You will need to be online

Comment: Have a look and see if there is a solution here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6955